# Use custom base class for ContentPage in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to use a custom ContentPage for my pages in Xamarin.Forms. I tried creating a custom class and specify the page in xaml like this:

```
<local:ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamarinFormsApp.Controls"
                   x:Class="XamarinFormsApp.Views.WelcomeView">

    <Label Text="{Binding MainText}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />

</local:ContentPage>
```

This would (normally) work in xaml, but gives me this error in Xamarin.Forms:

```
Error   7   The "XamlG" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Exception: Can't load types from xmlns clr-namespace:XamarinFormsApp.Controls
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG.GetNamespace(String namespaceuri)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG.GetType(String nsuri, String type, IList`1 typeArguments, Func`2 getNamespaceOfPrefix)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG.GenerateFile(String xamlFile, String outFile)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__20.MoveNext() XamarinFormsApp.iOS
```

Is this (yet) unsupported or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this was fixed in `Xamarin.Forms 1.0.6197` released on 2014-06-04.

also, your xmlns:local misses the `assembly` attribute. It should be `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamarinFormsApp.Controls;assembly=XamarinFormsApp"`

UPDATE:
the assembly part in the xmlns is no longer required if you're loading types from the same assembly

Comment: Cool, didn't know the forms was distributed via NuGet! Normally in xaml (and in this case, I didn't have to do that as well). Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same problem, but nuget shows no updates to the packages and the version numbers on the nuget package and assembly references are all higher than the one stated in the answer. Is this broken again? Is there another solution? Mine is a shared project not a PCL, but that shouldn't really make a difference.

Comment: Wait, I was wrong - the nuget package I currently have is only 1.0.6186. Unfortunately the nuget update function isn't working for some reason.

Comment: I  had to include the assembly name in the XAML namespace declaration to resolve the runtime exception. For Windows' XAML, the local assembly is implicit. However, for Xamarin.Forms I had to explicitly identify the assembly for the namespace for the binding to take place.

Comment: I had to include the assembly name in the XAML also to resolve getting an issue with InitializeComponent() in the code behind. 'InitializeComponent does not exist in the current context'